# What is this type of field called? (multiple custom text select inputs)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

An application I like has this field for inputting multiple custom text inputs. It's a really clean solution that I would like to use in my own project, however, I don't know what it's called. Any idea what this type of field is called in swing?

(this is a java project)

[image]

Comment: That is no single swing component, it is something custom that could be constructed from a number of different components all put together or extended and added to. For example, the [\n x] is likely a container with a text area on the left, and a button aligned to the right side, and the area you can type in is likely a text field that gets offset based on the location of any previous sequences, and it is all housed within another container with a border and a button aligned the the right side

Comment: Can you not decompile the application?

Comment: The inputs are usually called tags.